# Looking for a horror paperback 1970s woman with arm outstretched, mouth open screaming, face covered in cobweb

Tags: story-identification, horror

Trying to locate the title of a horror anthology from the 70s, all I can remember is the picture on the cover, a photograph of a woman with arm outstretched, possibly caught in brambles, her mouth was open, maybe screaming and covered with a gauzy cobweb, I remember thinking she must not have liked having to pose with a very real looking cobweb covering her open mouth, I think the background may have been a deep lilac blue, I think the cover was more interesting than the stories as cannot remember any of them, I think maybe Robert Bloch may have featured but not at all certain of that, does anyone know what this book is? I have done numerous image searches, using various terms and saw many books of that era that I had forgotten about, but nothing showing that one. I have searched the Sphere images  and other publishers of that time like Fontana and Pan, but nothing showing the particular book I am trying to find.

Answer (score 7):

Could it be the 1970 Sphere paperback anthology [*The House in the Valley & Other Tales of Terror*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?283679) edited by [Kurt Singer](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?10628)? The [cover](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/e/ea/THHSNTHVLL1970.jpg) does show a screaming woman with outstretched arm and cobwebs:

[image]

Nothing by [Robert Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Bloch) in it, but another famous "RB", [Ray Bradbury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Bradbury), is represented by ["The Handler"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64831), a short story which was dramatized as [the 27 October 1992 episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0683216/) of [The Ray Bradbury Theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ray_Bradbury_Theater), available at [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jST_0Vdi4I).

Comment: You know, I think that must be the one! Thank you so much, it was driving me nuts trying to recall it. For some reason I was convinced the woman had a cobweb completely covering her mouth, I guess I must have seen something else like that and was getting the two mixed up.

Comment: @evelynne You might be mixing it up with *The Best of HP Lovecraft: Bloodcurdling Tales of Horror and the Macabre*, which has an introduction by Robert Bloch, and the back cover has (among other things) a person wrapped in spiderweb.